# Rvalue to forwarding references

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading the [reference collapsing rules](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) and I have a question: why if I pass a **rvalue A** to

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&&);
```

T is deduced to be A?

e.g. if I pass `std::string()` to the function `T` is deduced to be `std::string`, why not `std::string&&`? It would have made more sense to me, what's the rationale behind deducing `T` to the type itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This merely lines up with what we expect in general from template type deduction:

```
template <class T> void vfoo(T );
template <class T> void lfoo(T& );
template <class T> void cfoo(T const& );
template <class T> void ffoo(T&& );

std::string x;
vfoo(x);            // deduce T = std::string
lfoo(x);            // deduce T = std::string
cfoo(x);            // deduce T = std::string
ffoo(x);            // deduce T = std::string& !
ffoo(std::move(x)); // deduce T = std::string
```

From [the original paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm), emphasis mine:

> When deducing a function template type using an lvalue argument matching to an rvalue reference, the type is deduced as an lvalue reference type. When deduction is given an rvalue argument, **type deduction proceeds just as with other types.**

It's the lvalue deduction case that's the exceptional one, which is why it gets an extra sentence in the type deduction rules. The rvalue case is typical - it lines up with the simple mental model of pasting in the deduced types to see what function you end up with. Called `T&&` with a `std::string`? Get `T = std::string` so that the argument reads `std::string&&`. Check.

Answer (score 3):

Because the function parameter type has the && on it and you are deducing the 'T' part of the expression.

So, 'passing' `std::string&&` to `T&&` will deduce `T` as `std::string`.

Substituting `std::string` as `T` in the expression `T&&` yields `std::string&&`.

It is kind of the same as deducing the `T` in the expression `T const&`; when 'passed' a `std::string` by const reference, the `T` part is deduced as `std::string`.

Comment: Your last sentence is wrong. `template<typename T>
void foo(T)` will never deduce a reference type.