# Ambiguity about rvalue reference passed and lvalue passed arguments on templated function

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, c++14, generic-programming

Consider this:

```
void test(int&& param){/*...*/}
int main(){
    int a{444};
    test(a);
}
```

Certainly It'll not compile because there's no conversion is defined for `int` to `int&&`. But the following code:

```
template<typename T>
void test(T&& param){/*..*/}


int main(){
    int a=826;
    test(a);
    return 0;
}
```

will compile. But why? What's the reason? There's nothing special about the later except that function test will instantiates for all types `T`. But we still need to pass rvalue as parameter. So why does it,the later, compile? - without any complaint. Then I tried the following:

```
template<typename T>
void test(T&& param){/*..*/}

template<typename T>
void test(T param){/*...*/}

int main(){
    int a=826;
    test(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains because function call is ambiguous on whether calling `test(T&& param)` with `T=int&` or `test(T param)` with `T=int`.
Now I am totally baffled on what to deduce. What special does the Template do in here? Why doesn't it conform with the rules on rvalues and lvalues?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rvalue to forwarding references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307479/rvalue-to-forwarding-references)   There might be a better dupe

Comment: Really good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward

Answer (score 0):

`T&&` in this case are sometimes called universal reference or forwarding reference. But the case is that is you're falling in a specific template type deduction rule. The type of `param` in this case will be `int&`, then you're not binding a lvalue into a rvalue.